Can't find ConvertAvroToOrc processor in NiFi
I want to convert avro to orc using NiFi but I'm not able to find the ConvertAvroToOrc processor in my NiFi processor list. I'm using NoFi version 1.25.0. Is there any alternative or any way to get the processor in the NiFi version I'm using?
Tried convert record processor but it does not have an option to write it as ORC type.
